# Querying the Historian seems to kill business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am on composer 0.16.0 and Fabric 1.0.4
While experimenting with Historian queries via composer-client consistently run into a situation when the network becomes non-responsive and the only way to reanimate it seems to be restarting the Fabric and redeploying the network.
The error follows:

```
>
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin)
>
```

So, the questions are:
1. Is this a known issue and is there a workaround? Happy to do more diagnostics and file it properly if that helps.
2. Any way to reboot the network without restarting the Fabric?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

so the error "The current identity has not been registered: admin" is fundamentally caused by the fact you are restarting your CA server each time - ie a new CA server, a new authority issuing new credentials effectively for 'admin' (and hence your present admin credentials from 'previous' in your card store are not recognised by the new CA server).

Suggest to

1) clear out old admin cards from your card store eg. `composer card delete --name admin@tutorial-network`

2) re-import your 'admin' card through playground or CLI - and do a `composer network ping` to retrieve credentials to the card store.

3) Reduce your Historian queries result sets by adding selection criteria

Note: To restart your existing Dev Fabric - just use `docker stop` to stop your containers - and `docker start` you can restart them from the same state (or use `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start` if you're familiar with that command). Else, use docker persistence to persist your data.

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html

Probably good to

Comment: Thanks! The thing is that I wasn't restarting the CA, at least not intentionally. What was happening is my code calling Historian queries was bombing out on some invalid params while tweaking it eventually leading to the aforementioned error after a number of runs.  So I was wondering if it's symptomatic of some problem in Composer or Fabric.

Comment: well you did say "the only way to reanimate it seems to be restarting the Fabric" (which means the CA server :-). Not that I'm aware of. As for invalid params, suggest to set up some logging / unit tests to check what goes into your queries etc.

Comment: This went from bad to worse. Not that I am running various usage scenarios connecting to the network via composer-client this failure happens left and right. Same error.  Where do I start diagnosing? @ PaulO'Mahony        #### Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The current identity has not been registered: admin)
18:22:13 worker.1       |      at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch (/Users/andrei/Development/Zest/Blockchain/zest-poc-web/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:713:34)

Comment: hi there, what OS and version of the OS are you running on? Also your node version? Thanks

Comment: OSX 10.13.2   Node v9.2.0.  I am running a sequence of transactions to create/update assets  and then the web app queries the assets in response to the event the transactions emit. I call registry.getAll() to fetch the assets which is probably suboptimal. Same scenario also generates transaction  failures with MVCC_READ_CONFLICT.  Thanks much!

Comment: Quick update.  1)replacing  registry.getAll()  with proper queries seemed to have solved the MVCC_READ_CONFLICT 2)Figured I wasn't properly disconnecting from the network in a couple of places. Fixed that and so far so good and the fabric's still alive. The tricky one was the Webstorm's debugger sending SIGKILL to the processes on stop thus skipping the proper process exit clean up code.